# Updating code for my application every week

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I’m creating a bot app in python using selenium, for people, but I would need to change the xpath code every week, how do I do this once I distribute the app to people?

Thanks In advance

Comment: How are going to distribute the app can you  specify

Comment: I’m going to make a web application app, and let them download it from a website I create

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to locate selectors using Id rather than XPath since there won't be any change to Id selector once a new feature(adding a table/div to the HTML)is added. Also, this reduces the rework effort to a large extend.

Comment: id or Xpath wouldn't matter becuase the website adds something new every week, and this 'new thing' has a new id and new everything, its like when spotify adds new songs they must update the code somehow, thats what i need to achieve thanks